# Binding super interfaces to sub interfaces with Ninject

Tags: c#, ninject

This code doesn't work.  I basically have some implementations of a super interface and a sub interface.  I'd like the super interface to return all the implementations and the sub interface return only the sub implementations.  I don't want to bind the sub implementations to both the sub and super interfaces, explicitly.  I'd like to just bind it to the sub interface and somehow bind the sub to the super.  I'm trying to set it up like this, but it's not working:

```
class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        IKernel kernel = new StandardKernel();
        kernel.Bind<ISuperInterface>().To<ISubInterface>(); // What can I do instead of this?
        kernel.Bind<ISuperInterface>().To<SuperImplementation>();
        kernel.Bind<ISubInterface>().To<SubImplementation>();

        var subs = kernel.GetAll<ISubInterface>(); // I want this to return a SubImplementation
        var supers = kernel.GetAll<ISuperInterface>(); // I want this to return a SuperImplementation and a SubImplementation

        Console.WriteLine(subs.Count());
        Console.WriteLine(supers.Count());
    }
}

public class SubImplementation : ISubInterface
{
}

public class SuperImplementation : ISuperInterface
{
}

public interface ISuperInterface
{
}

public interface ISubInterface : ISuperInterface
{
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Ninject supports interface seggregation:

```
kernel.Bind<ISuperInterface>().To<SuperImplementation>();
kernel.Bind<ISuperInterface, ISubInterface>().To<SubImplementation>();
```

Or if you are using conventions you can use `BindAlInterfaces`